# Need to access two different python version i.e Python 2.6.6 and Python 3.6.3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to access two python version
1. Pycell studio python 2.6.6 which is used to work on layout section
2. Python 3.6.3 which is used for internal application

I can not access both versions at time.
When I install Python 2.6.6 it changed following environment variable
PYTHONHOME, PYHTONPATH, CNI_DISPLAY_DIR, CNI_ROOT, OA_PLUGIN_PATH etc
this variable does not allow me to use python 3.6.3 and gives "code registry error" whenever I launched it.

Is there any setting through which I can use both python version at a same time?

Comment: I recommend you use virtual environments. You can use virtualenv or conda (anaconda). I recommend conda. You can have multiple environments with different python version and other libraries

Comment: But you cant use two different versions of python to run a same file at the same time but only some lines for each version in only one run

Comment: Pycell studio is specifically used to work on layout view which is supported by cadence and Through anaconda we can not install this Pycell studio pyhton. You can do google for more information

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run both at the same time in the same file.  However, like someone mentioned above in the comments, there are ways to have files running with different versions of Python running simultaneously.  Another way to get around your problem (though not as great for efficiency/performance) is to output and re-input whatever data needs shared across these two different Python version code files.  Hopefully that makes sense, but comment if I need to be clearer.

*Alex Chung | Director of Operations, VTNatSec | achung@vtnatsec.org*